# Ruby inject condition

Tags: ruby

I have an array filled with hashes. The data structure looks like this:

```
students = [
  {
    "first_name" => "James",
    "last_name" => "Sullivan",
    "age" => 20,
    "study_results" => {"CAR" => 1, "PR1" => 1, "MA1" => 1, "BEN" => 2, "SDP" => nil}
  }
]
```

I want to find students with the mark `1` from at least two subjects.

I tried to convert the hash with marks into an array and then use the `inject` method to count the number of `1` and find out if the number is `> 1`:

```
students.select{|student
  (
    (student["study_results"].to_a)
    .inject(0){|sum, x| sum += 1 if x.include?(1)}
  ) > 1
}
```

Is there any way to put a condition into the method, or should I find a different way to solve it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I commend you for attempting to solve this before posting, but you made it unnecessarily complicated. I'd write it like this:

```
students.select{|student| student['study_results'].values.count(1) >= 2}
```

That's all, no need for `inject`. You were misusing it here.

Ruby collections have TONS of useful methods. If you find yourself using `inject` or `each`, there's a better method for this, 90% of the time.

#### Explanation:

```
student['study_results'] # => {"CAR"=>1, "PR1"=>1, "MA1"=>1, "BEN"=>2, "SDP"=>nil}
student['study_results'].values # => [1, 1, 1, 2, nil]
student['study_results'].values.count(1) # => 3
student['study_results'].values.count(2) # => 1
student['study_results'].values.count(3) # => 0
student['study_results'].values.count(nil) # => 1
```

#### Documentation

- [Hash#values](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.1/Hash.html#method-i-values)
- [Array#count](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.1/Array.html#method-i-count)